# how to clear data cache of the application through code

Tags: android

i want to clear data cache programmatic of my application that is increasing, right now i am clearing from Settings->Applications->Manage Application->My Application->Clear Cache.

but i want to do it by programmatic, please help me.

Answer (score 5):

Just a guess:

Delete these files by knowing their absolute path to cache directory - getCacheDir() - http://d.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir().