# I want to open a new activity after clearing my app data

Tags: java, android

```
try {

    // clearing app data
    String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    runtime.exec("pm clear "+packageName);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, SplashActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I want to open new activity after clear data code on button click, this above is my button click code but when I run it, it clears the data but does not open a new activity. Please help thanks in advance

Comment: Check Log cat for Errors . Have you registered `SplashActivity` in Manifest ?

Comment: yes....no error this code close the app

Comment: [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).

Comment: suggest me any other source code in which I can clear app data and start application again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134103/clear-applications-data-programmatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993396/android-restart-app-after-clearing-cache-and-data

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code. But it has one limitation as clearApplicationUserData() requires minimum SDK version 19.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, SplashActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, pendingIntent);

System.exit(0);
((ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).clearApplicationUserData();
```

Comment: your code is not working, actually in my application I use gplus login so I want gplus logout with clear data code, which is not working with your code,  gplus account is still login with this code, please provide me code regarding to my concept

Comment: then replace last line of my code with yours (i.e) which you used in try catch block to clear the app data